# .fadeTo is not fading in slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to add in a .fadeTo on a div and finally got it to work

I have this:

```
<section class= "hue innerS1" id="hue" >
    <p class="huep innerS1">BRILLIANT-HUED</p>

    <script>
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            $('[class^="hue"]').each(function () {
                if (($(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 150) {
                    $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
                } else {
                    $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</section>
```

But when I scroll to the div it appears in milliseconds not to what it has been set to. When I scroll up back past the div .fadeTo works then.

I cant see whats wrong as both lines of code are the same so it should work, no?

**Edit**

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zackreid/ot0xhk9r/1/)

But as you can see it works in on this I might need to update the jquery that I am using. It acting a bit funny though

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: @j08691 got one sorted, forgot to added it when posting.

Comment: Looks fine to me, what's the actual behaviour you're trying to achieve? You want it to fade in when it's 150px from the top of the screen? Also, the JSFiddle JavaScript is different to the code sample you've provided in your question...

Comment: What do you mean by it *"acts a bit funny"*, it seems fine to me. Describe what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution may be in using of number instead word.

So, instead word `slow` use any number (the higher number, more time it takes - here it is, for example 800 - but number may be different as you need). It will allow you to set exactly how long it will do.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        $('[class^="hue"]').each(function () {
            if (($(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop()) < 150) {
                $(this).stop().fadeTo(800, 1);
            } else {
                $(this).stop().fadeTo(800, 0);
            }
        });
    });
```